# jQuery append with `.load()`without using `.get()`

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, jquery-get

It appears that one (of many) differences between `.load()` and `.get()` is that the former can use an HTML fragment, while the latter requires that said HTML fragment be a fully valid XML structure.

I'm trying to load an external file that is a fragment of HTML and append it to an element. However load, by default, replaces--not appends.

It seems the common solution to this is to use `.get()` instead, but that's not going to work in my situation as the file is likely rarely to be a valid xml document.

Is there a way to use `.load()` for this?

And example of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
</table>
```

and the html file:

```
<tr><td>World</td></tr>
```

Can I use `.load()` to append the TR in the external file into the TABLE?

Comment: Why dont you use $,ajax? And do whatever you want with the responseText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also using `get()` should be better you might use load:

```
var $tr = $("<tr/>").load('ur/file.html',function(){
  $tr.appendTo("#myTable")
})
```

Get

```
$.get( url, function(data){
  $(data).appendTo("#myTable")
}, 'text' );
```

Comment: the first example wipes out the entire DOM as soon as the `load` is called.  However, the second works wonderfully. It appears that my issue was forgetting to tell `get` that I want to load it as text. Thanks!